# How to use the doValidate method of mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   kind: {
      type: String,
      enum: { 
         values: ["dollar", "euro", "pound", "lira"],
         message: "only dollar, euro, pound or lira are allowed"
      }
      required: [true, "kind field is required"]
   }
   // ... other fields
})
```

I have the following code:

```js
app.post("/route", async (req, res, next) => {
    //  write code here
})
```

I want to validate only one path from that schema, I don't to validate everything, I just want to validate one field, so what I did according to this [git discussion](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/discussions/12004) is the following:

```js
app.post("/route", async (req, res, next) => {
    //  
    await mySchema.path("kind").doValidate(req.body.kind)
})
```

but this did not work and I got the following error:

```
.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1332
        fn(err);
        ^

TypeError: fn is not a function
    at .../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1332:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

How can I use doValidate and get the benefit of it? and why there's no documentation on how to use it?

- and is there a way I can *promisify* it?

Comment: The documentation can be found here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematype.html#schematype_SchemaType-doValidate

Comment: promisifying this method wouldn't be any different than any other promisification of a callback based method. Create promise, call method. On callback, if error, reject, if success, resolve.

Comment: @KevinB, yes I know, but they're not giving a description not even one example about it, in fact, I would never hear about it if I didn't read the git link I provided in my question above

Comment: @KevinB, yes, promisifying, maybe I can use Node.js `util.promisify()` Method thanks

Comment: and I am noticing that it's (the doValidate) throwing a "ValidatorError" instead of "ValidationError" which normally gets thrown by a schema